# Start and stop capturing while video is playing

Tags: premiere

I have a long video that I am trying to shorten.  I want to be able to play through the video and, while it is playing, select the points at which I want to start and end my clips.

I want to do this for multiple clips until I play to the end of my video without having to stop.  Some of my clips will be very short shots so it needs to be fast enough for that.

In the end I should have a shorter version of my video composed of all the pieces I've sliced.  This way I can quickly achieve a first draft of my edited video.  Later I can slowly improve it and fix all of my mistakes.

I would like to know how to do this with Premiere. If it is not possible, do you know any other editing software that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main way I can think of to do this, the first, which requires a little work after the fact, but certainly won't interrupt your play back, is to set marker points as you watch through the timeline.  Put the entire video in the timeline and then use the M key to place timeline markers at each point you wish to make a cut.  After watching through, you can place razor cuts on each marker and ripple delete every other section.

The other option, which I'm not sure if it will work without interrupting playback or not, is to set in and out points using shortcut keys.  I will set an in point, O will set an outpoint and Ctrl-K to add the edit to the timeline.  If that does end up interrupting playback, there is one other option that might work indirectly.

You could also try using a multi-cam edit with nothing on the second track.  This would let you monitor what is on your main playback and you could cut to and away from it whenever you like.  At the end you would just have to remove the empty space and get rid of the other track.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not professional video editor familiar with Premiere but I know your requirements can be met by some simple video editing software I recommended here: [Simple Video Editing Tool?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4233/simple-video-editing-tool/9384#9384)
Here are the solution steps I recommend for you. I won't recommend the best video editing here, but you can pick up anyone (most of them can achieve it as long as it has "Split" and "Delete" function.)

- Firstly, download any of free simple video editing software in your
  PC as per different version.
- Secondly, Import the video you want to edit and then drag to the
  timeline (or other editing area like board).
- Thirdly, Play your video in preview windows and click "Stop" in the
  first clip you want to second-editing. Now use the simple but
  powerful "Split" button, which is always designed to "scissors".
  (Let's set it as point 1)
- Fourthly, continue to preview the video and stop in the end of the
  first clip you want to second-editing. Use "Split" again. (Let's set
  it as point 2)
- Fifthly, Then continue to find the third "Split" point for your next
  clips you want to second-editing (Let's set it as point 3) and end
  with point 4 as the end of your second clip
- Sixthly, now you need to use "Delete" function which is can delete
  the clips you don't need (the part from point 2 to point 3) in
  further editing.

Then repeat the steps from 3-5, you will get multiple clips you need to second editing. 
To this point, you have 2 options:

1. Save all those clips in your PC (which will merge to the whole video
   automatically) and then edit them later with more professional video
   program.
2. Zoom in/out all those clips to further editing in this simple video
   editing software with other functions. I may need more details about
   your questions to solve your further problems.
   Check the image below to get more intuitive understanding.
   [image]

Comment: This doesn't really address the problem that the OP wanted though.  He's looking for a way to do it without having to stop the video for each cut.